# printing the value of Local variable

Tags: java

```
package Student;

public class Example
{
    int i = 10;//instance variable which is created under class

    void age()// age is method here
    {   
        int j=11;// local variable which is created under method

}

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Example ex = new Example();//Creating the object 
        System.out.println("Display the valule" ex.age());


        ex.age();

    }
}
```

I am not able to print the j value..

Comment: Java tutorial: [Returning a value from a method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html)

Comment: You need to return `j` from `age`. Also, you need to say what problems you're having specifically when you ask. This is a very vague question

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.println("Display the valule" + ex.age());

You are expecting the above line to print the age but it will not since your age method is returning nothing.

Try this:

```
int age()// Now your age method will return an integer value
{   
        int j=11;// local variable which is created under method
        return j;
}
```

Comment: you need the plus on the sysout

Comment: @Isac Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 0):

You need to return `j` so your function should look like this:

```
int age()// age is method here
{   
        int j=11;
        return j; // return j
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The sysout will print any value that is passed within. The method age() is not returning any value. The age() method should be modified to have a return type of int and return the variable j instead of just setting the value. You should typically use the getters and setters as below and call set method and use the get method for printing in sysout.

```
void setAge() {
 j = 11;
}

int getAge() {
   return j;
}
```